# Android Manifest files attributes for Tablet

Tags: android

I've an app targeted to Gingerbread. What attributes do I need to change/add in manifest file to make it run on a tablet?

Comment: Probably nothing, but that is difficult to tell, since we cannot see your manifest, and therefore do not know what you have.

Comment: what I want to know is that if there are additional attribs needs to be defined in order to enable it to run on tablets. In my knowledge, the only thing will be good to have is: android:xlargeScreens= true. Are there any other such attributes which helps a gingerbread targeted app to run on tablets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add anything.
If you wan't your app to run only in tablets you should filter the devices allowed by screen size, adding the following code to your manifest:

```
<supports-screens 
 android:smallScreens="false"
 android:normalScreens="false"
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:xLargeScreens="true"
 android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" 
              />
```

Comment: Note that this configuration will mean that the app will be filtered out of the Play Store for phones.